# Data disapearing after AJAX request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, web

I'm learning jquery and using fake data for Ajax requests. Here is simple HTML:

```js
$(function() {
  $('.tasks__form').on('submit', function() {
    let id = $('.tasks__input').val();
    $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos',
      data: {
        id: id
      },
      caches: false,
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(result) {
        console.log(result);
      },
    }).done(function(data) {
      $.each(data, function(key, value) {
        $.each(value, function(indexInArray, valueOfElement) {
          $('.tasks').append('<div>' + valueOfElement + '</div>');
        });
      });
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="tasks">
    <form action="#" method="GET" class="tasks__form">
      <input class="tasks__input" name="send-id" type="text" placeholder="Type an id" />
      <button name="send-id" type="submit" class="tasks__button">
            Find task by id
          </button>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Everything was working yesterday. But today, when I run the script, it builds divs with data and then everything disappears (without reloading).

Comment: Your problem is because the form is being submit, so it's causing a page redirect. You need to prevent the standard form submission - see the duplicate for details on how to do that. I can't see how this would ever have been working without that line of code, so I can only assume you accidentally removed it.

Comment: thank you so much! I don't remember how it was working I just woke up and it doesn't.